# Cannot convert source type to target type

Tags: c#

I've got this subclass implementing my Interface and there are no errors in terms of satisfying the contract.  However when I try to set the current session in the sub class's constructor I get this compile-time error when it tries to compare the variable type with the returned type of GetCurrentSession():

**"Cannot convert source type IAPISession to target type FacebookSession"**

Ok why?  Facebook is a IAPISession... right???  polymorphism at play is my thinking so it should be happy with this comparison.  Not sure here.

```
public class FacebookSession : IAPISession
{
    private FacebookSession currentSession;

    private FacebookSession()
    {
        currentSession = GetCurrentSession();
    }

    ...more code

    public IAPISession GetCurrentSession()
    {
        // my logic is here...whatever that may be
    }
     ... more code
 }
```

**Updated**

here's my actual interface:

```
public interface IAPISession
{
    #region Properties

    int SessionID { get; }

    string UserID { get; }

    bool SessionHasExpired { get; }

    DateTime ExpirationDate { get; }

    void LogOut(); // expires the session & sets SessionHasExpired

    #endregion Properties

    #region Methods

    IAPISession GetCurrentSession();

    #endregion Methods

}
```

This interface will be utilized across any API wrapper projects of ours (e.g. FlickrSession, etc.)

Comment: so just a quick comment.  I see a lot of people here gunning for a Singleton because it's close to looking and functioning like a Singleton.  But the usage of sessions in my case are a 1x1 relationship..user to unique session.  A user will have many unique types of sessions (i.e. FacebookSession, PicasaSession, FlickrSession, and so on).  So UserA will have several unique sessions depending on what API they've signed into via our code.  When looking at this page from SwDevMan81, it reads " lets clients access its unique instance".  Singletons are to be used for many to one resource situations

Comment: A few days ago I thought I was just going to make these singletons but a good programmer friend of mine says in my case, it's the wrong use..you should not use a Singleton here due the fact that you're not sharing anything...that is a session is specific to one person, one thread. It's not that many threads "users" are using -one- specific session floating around. They each have multiple of their own based on what APIs they're logging into. As I look at that article by Gang of Four, it completely backs up what he stated, that it's many to one (singleton) relationships where it makes sense

Comment: Thanks all for your help..really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this needs an explicit cast. You are receiving a generic (interface) session, but you want to use specific (Facebook) methods/fields.

You **might** envisage a scenario where `GetCurrentSession()` returns a different type of `IAPISession`!

- use `currentSession =
  (FacebookSession)
  GetCurrentSession();`
- use a `try` block around the cast to
  catch this possibility. I assume your
  code would get confused if it weren't
  a type of `FacebookSession`, so you
  need to deal with that situation.

### Addition

Just to clarify:

```
FacebookSession fbSess;
IAPISession     genSess;
FacebookSession getFbSession() { ... return this; }
IAPISession     getSession()   { ... return this; }

genSess = getSession();        // legal
genSess = getFbSession();      // legal - implicit cast works as FacebookSession 
                               // is always a kind of IAPISession
fbSess  = getFbSession();      // legal
fbSess  = getSession();        // ILLEGAL - not all IAPISession's will be
                               // kinds of FacebookSession
fbSess  = (FacebookSession) getSession();
                               // legal, but might throw a class cast exception
                               // if it isn't a FacebookSession.
```

and likewise,

```
genSess = fbSess;              // ok, implicit cast to generic type
fbSess  = genSess;             // ILLEGAL, it may not be a FacebookSession
fbSess  = (FacebookSession) genSess; 
                               // legal but can throw an exception
```

Comment: so unlike abstract classes..whereas if I were to do something like this: MyMethod(SomeAbstractType type) where I could pass any subtype to this method that inherits SomeAbstractType, the same technique is not true to interfaces.  Just because I have MyMethod(IAPISession session) doesn't mean I can pass in any subclass which has implemented IAPISession?  So polymorphism works differently in the case of interfaces? Or am I just completely missing something beginner here that I've not taken into account with the concept of polymorphism and interfaces?

Comment: OK I've answered this by adding an example

Comment: got it was wrong interfaces are no different than abstract classes in the polymorphism relm...you can definitely swap out an interface for its subtype in lets say a method param as I talkd about in my last reply.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Although `GetCurrentSession` might actually be returning a `FacebookSession`, the return type is `IAPISession` and there is no implicit cast from an interface to any class implementing that interface.

Either change the return type of the `GetCurrentSession` method to `FacebookSession` or change the `currentSession` field type to `IAPISession` (or both if it makes sense to do so).

Comment: but I thought due to polymorphism (an interface variable or lets say method param can take in any class which has implemented that interface into your method or set to your variables...just like an abstract class method param or variable type can take in any subclass which has implemented it).  Isn't that a major purpose of using interfaces due to polymorphism??

Comment: (Either change the return type of the GetCurrentSession method to FacebookSession) I can't because that doesn't satisfy my Interface contract. My Interface defines an abstact public IAPISession GetCurrentSession(); method becaue my intent is that this interface will be implemented by other API type sessions (Flickr, etc.) and reused across other api projects of ours. So that means if I make the return type IAPISession on that method, I should be able to return that subtype even though the return type is set to IAPISession I thought.

Comment: It looks like you're part way towards the Singleton pattern.  As it stands you have a GetCurrentSession() method that is not static so you'll need to create a sesson in order to get the current sesson!  If a user of this class already has a reference to an instance of it, why would it ever need to call GetCurrentSession - it already has a session!

Comment: Polymorphism allows you to treat all `FacebookSession`s "as an" `IAPISession` but you can't do it the other way around since an `IAPISesion` may actually be a `TwitterSession`, for example.

Comment: gotcha, so that's why I was able to send in any subclass which implemented an abstract class in a method expecting that abstract class param type.

Comment: Daniel, I tried to make that Interface method signature for GetCurrentSession static due to the very reasons you're stating but you can't declare a static method in an Interface, so...

Comment: So does that mean if you have a need for certain static members that you know EVERY wrapper you create in the future will need (i.e. a session will need a common way to get at it)...that if you expect to access that method statically though, then keep it out of the interface even though technically you think it should be in the contract?  Because an interface doesn't support statics?  So taht forces me to basically potentially keep out common members in some Interfaces I'm creating because I need to use them as static in the implementation?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern for info on the Singleton pattern (it has examples in C#).  How you go about this depends on what you're trying to do.  Will you have a "current session" of each session type or just one "current session" for thewhole application/user of just one session type (although you may not know exactly which it is due to polymorphsm)?

Comment: I've looked and even used that pattern before.  That's not what I want here for the session.

Comment: the user will have a possibility of one facebook, one flickr, one etc. session.  It's a 1-to-1 relationship per session meaning user-to-session..not many users to one session(resource).  I was told that Singletons should only be used to share functionality amongst for example lets say you have multiple threads..or in my case I have created Singletons for things like Certificates where everyone on the website would need an instance of this cert but there's only one cert out there that they need for whatever functionality we're providing them.  In that case a Singleton is the way you go.

Comment: So again the Session is 1x1 here is always going to be a 1x1 - user-to-specific API session.  One user may have logged into Flickr and Facebook thus those are 2 implementations so a FacebookSession and a FlickrSession for example will be created and floating around.  I need to occassionally check to see if that object is still in memory...so all I have to do is just go and look for that object and see if it is available...no singleton needed.  So every wrapper project we create (Flickr, Facebook, others) will be required to use this Interface pattern - they will all have those common members

Comment: so yes it's  "Will you have a "current session" of each session type".  We already have a session for the overall app..this is for photo specific functionality on some of our pages.

Answer (score 1):

You need the other way around:

```
public class FacebookSession : IAPISession
{
    private IAPISession currentSession;

    private FacebookSession()
    {
        currentSession = GetCurrentSession();
    }

    ...more code

    public FacebookSession GetCurrentSession()
    {
        // my logic is here...whatever that may be
    }
     ... more code
 }
```

If you want to use the specific implementation inside the class, then I would instantiate that class in the constructor.  Then just return that instance in you GetCurrentSession class. For example:

```
public class FacebookSession : IAPISession
{
    private FacebookSession currentSession;

    private FacebookSession()
    {
        currentSession = new FacebookSession();
    }

    ...more code

    public IAPISession GetCurrentSession()
    {
        return currentSession;
    }
     ... more code
 }
```

And like Daniel mentions, this is getting close to the singleton pattern.  See an implementation of it [here](http://dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx).  See the section under `.NET Optimized Code`

Comment: but not good if your logic requires specific FacebookSession methods.

Comment: IF `GetCurrentSession()` is defined on the interface, that would also need to return type `IAPISession`.

Comment: In which case it could just return IAPISession

Comment: See this is where I don't see the benefit in this particular case of making that currentSession backing field an interface type instead of the subclass type itself. I mean I don't plan on utilizing that private variable in any other way...as to gain any polymorphism benefits from that. So is it really overkill to just make that local field type IAPISession just to satisfy the contract? I say no...like Sanjay says, this is a specific Sub type and I know the type.  If I'm looking at the intent or that there is a good reason to do this other than "satisfying the error" please do explain to us.

Comment: see my other replies in this thread to others why I don't want a Singleton here...

Comment: I have used Singletons before but it's not what I want for this scenario which is a session...

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can't cast from a more generic type (IAPISession, in your case) to a more specific type (FacebookSession) **without using an explicit cast** unless there is an implict cast defined.

Think about what would happen in this case:

```
var flickrSession = new FlickrSession();
var iApiFlickrSession = flickrSession as IAPISession;

var faceBookSession = iApiFlickrSession;
```

You can be guaranteed that an instance of FacebookSession is also an instance of IAPISession but you can't always be guaranteed that an instance of IAPISession is also an instance of FacebookSession.

In that second case, the compiler wouldn't know what to do.

What you could try is using the as operator (which may or may not work in your case). The value will be null if the cast fails:

```
currentSession = GetCurrentSession() as FacebookSession;
```

Comment: Of course you can cast from more generic to more specific.  (In your example, you will get a run-time error,  but if the typed matched, it would work fine).

Comment: would you even need the as?  I mean wouldn't it know by polymorphism that flickrSession is a IAPISession in your second line?

Comment: well, I'd rather design by compile time errors...good practice and must makes sense and is why typed is "good"

Answer (score 0):

You must be explicit when you want to do that:

```
private FacebookSession() 
{ 
    currentSession = (FacebookSession) GetCurrentSession(); 
}
```

Note that is will throw an exception of the object returned by `GetCurrentSession()` is not actually a `FacebookSession`.

UPDATE:

You seem to be confusing what happens at run-time with what happens at compile time:

```
    currentSession = GetCurrentSession();
```

This fails to compile, because, while the object returned by `GetCurrentSession` *may* be a `FacebookSession` object at run-time, all the compiler knows about it is that it implements `IAPISession`, and there could be many non-FacebookSeesion object which implement `IAPISession`.

```
    currentSession = (FacebookSession) GetCurrentSession();
```

Here you are telling the compiler, "Trust me -- when we run this, it's going be a FacebookSession object.  If I'll lyin', you can crash the run with an exception!"

```
    currentSession = (int) GetCurrentSession();
```

This won't compile.  You are trying to say "Trust me" blah-blah-blah, but the compiler calls your bluff say, "Baloney! There is no way a IAPISession can ever be an `int`"

Comment: GetCurrentSession DOES returns an IAPISession which sould be interchangable via polymorphism I thought since FaceookSession implements IAPISession

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: Yes, so what you are trying won't crash at run-time.  But you still must cast it!