# Cannot convert source type to target type (of known interface for T)?

Tags: c#, generics, boxing

I can't seem to compile the following code; I get the error:

```
Cannot convert source type 'MyConcreteInterfaceThing' to target type 'T'
```

How come?

Here is the code:

```
public interface IMyInterfaceThing
{
    void doStuff();
}

public record struct MyConcreteInterfaceThing : IMyInterfaceThing
{
    public void doStuff()
    {
        // code here
    }
}

public class MyServiceThingy
{
    public void AddItem<T>(T item) where T : IMyInterfaceThing
    {
        var myList = new List<T>();

        var someCondition = /** something interesting happens... **/ 1;
        T   thingToPutIntoList;
        switch (someCondition)
        {
            case 1:
                thingToPutIntoList = new MyConcreteInterfaceThing();
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("Faulty condition");
        }

        myList.Add(thingToPutIntoList);
    }
}
```

The error occurs on line:

```
thingToPutIntoList = new MyConcreteInterfaceThing();
```

I do know it works when I change `T` into `IMyInterfaceThing` in the implementation body.

But, why is this needed? Can't the compiler derive that `T` is of type `IMyInterfaceThing` ?

Also: I try to prevent boxing my structs (if possible).

(I have seen [Cannot convert source type to target type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523428/cannot-convert-source-type-to-target-type) , but this is I think a different scenario / question)

Comment: Consider this: an apple is a fruit, and so is a pear. Your generic constraint is `where T : Fruit`. Imagine you call `AddItem<Apple>(myApple)` but then you write `T thingToPutIntoList = new Pear();`, which is equivalent to `Apple thingToPutIntoList = new Pear();` when calling the method as described before. Clearly this doesn't make sense. That's essentially what the code you have shown us is doing. It seems like you really just want `thingToPutIntoList = item`?

Comment: _"Can't the compiler derive that T is of type IMyInterfaceThing ?"_ - that's true, it is, but `List<T>` is not. If `AddItem<Apple>(myApple);` is called, then it's actually `List<Apple>`, `T thingToPutIntoList` is actually `Apple thingToPutIntoList`, etc. so coming in with a `Pear` is naturally going to cause problems.

Comment: Hmm. I want the list to be able to contain Apples and Pears. Ah, but I used <T> so I can enforce it is a value type (and not reference type). So that combination makes this impossible.

Comment: Maybe you want the `new()` constraint, and do `thingToPutIntoList = new T();`?

Answer (score -2):

According to me a better way would be instead of **T   thingToPutIntoList** you can use **IMyInterfaceThing thingToPutIntoList**. Hope this helps

Comment: thx. Does this make sure I keep my value types? I don't want to box my structs.

Comment: Interfaces are reference types, so value types will be boxed.